# What happens physically in the horizon distance in predominant matter universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, event-horizon

Setting constant curvature $k = 0$, the Friedmann equation takes the simple form:
$\dot{a}^{2} = \dfrac{8 \pi G \epsilon_o}{3 c^2}a^{-(1+3\omega)}$
If We suppose: $a \propto t^q$. We have $a(t) = (\dfrac{t}{t_o})^{2/(3+3\omega)}$. Then the horizon distance take the form: $d_{hor}(t_o) = c \int_{0}^{t_o} \dfrac{dt}{a(t)} \ = \  \dfrac{c}{H_o} \dfrac{2}{1+ 3\omega}$.

If we consider a universe with only non-relativistic matter, then $ \omega = 0$ and $ d_{hor}(t_o) = 3ct_o$.

MY doubt is: What is the physical meaning of the horizontal distance in the universe with only matter being greater than the distance that light travels?

Answer (score 1):

The horizon distance, and any other distance defined in this way, is the distance from the horizon (or something else) *right now*. When the light you observe was emitted, the object was closer to you, but in the meantime space has expanded.

Hence, whereas in a *static* universe the horizon distance would be $ct_0$, in an expanding universe it will be larger.